# GROUP BY with '+' expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with `GROUP BY` statement.

I have a table TEST:
[image]

And I want to execute following select statement:

```
select sum(a)
from TEST
group by a+b
```

Here is the result:

```
SUM(A)
3
1
3
```

It works, but I have no idea why. What expression a+b does with `GROUP BY` statement?

Thanks.

//edit, sorry for that huge image. I will change it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this...  `SELECT 2 + NULL` and see what you get.

The answer isn't `2`, it's `NULL`.

So, using your example data...

```
  A  |  B  | A+B
-----+-----+-----
  1  |  0  |  1
  2  | NULL| NULL
  3  |  2  |  5
  1  | NULL| NULL
 NULL|  2  | NULL
```

The sum of `A` where `A+B` is `NULL` is... `3`
The sum of `A` where `A+B` is `1` is...... `1`
The sum of `A` where `A+B` is `5` is...... `3`

You can circumvent this using `COALESCE(a, 0) + COALESCE(b, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what is does you can give it the select expression itslef

```
select  a+b,sum(a) from TEST group by a+b
```

It is null while adding with any value and null.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you in understanding.

```
       select a,a+b from test11;
       +------+------+------+
       | a    | b    | a+b  |
       +------+------+------+
       |    1 |    2 |    3 |
       |    2 |    2 |    4 |
       |    2 |    3 |    5 |
       |    4 |    3 |    7 |
       |    3 |    4 |    7 |
       |    0 |    7 |    7 |
       +------+------+------+
```

DB will create the temp table with added col containing (a+b) and  then perform the group by on that col.

Comment: Why not use the actual data in the OP's example?  Specifically, including `NULL` values?

Comment: @Dems Yeap. Should have done that. I looked at question as asking regarding using *+* in group by